# Element of finite order

Tags: group-theory

If G be a group of finite order and the quotient group G/H has an element of order 'n' , then show that G also has an element of order 'n' ...I don't understand how to approach the problem and prove the result...please help !

Comment: Let $gH \in G/H$ have order $n$. What can you say about the orde of $g$ in $G$?

Comment: Also: if $g$ has order $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, what order does $g^a$ have?  Put this and Derek's hint together and you should have the answer.